data:read scope limit on authentication API version 2
After upgrading to version 2 of the authentication API, we seem to get an error when trying to retrieve the access token for multiple urns (>9 IFC models).
Here's how we're defining the scope parameter:
const modelScopes = models
      .map((model) => {
        const modelUrn = Buffer.from(model.forge_urn, "base64url").toString();
        return `data:read:${modelUrn}`;
      })
      .join(" ");

And here's how we're using it:
post(FORGE_AUTH_ENDPOINT, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
    },
    form: {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        scope: modelScopes,
    },
})

We had no issues here before, but the new API version seems to stop us from retrieving an access token when the "modelScopes" parameter is too long.
We frequently use more than 10 models, so we need a way to fix this.
Edit: After looking in the documentation here, https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/, it's clear that the 2000 character limit is causing the problem. Would be very happy if this could be increased, as these urns can be quite long.

We raised the scope length limit to 3000 for the POST /token endpoint needed for 2-legged authentication.
The GET /authorize endpoint for 3-legged authentication needs to be used in the browser where you'll run into a near 2000 limit anyway, so we did not change the 2000 character scope length limit there.
